# Why doesn't my directive using '=' bind?

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have the following:

**case-directive.js**

```
.directive('case', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/template/caseload/case.tmpl.html',
            scope: {
                item: '=item'
            }
        }
    }]);
```

**case.tmpl.html**

```
<div class="case">
    <div><span>{{lastname}}</span>, <span>{{firstname}}</span></div>
</div>
```

**caseload.tmpl.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="c in caseload">
    <!-- does NOT work, empty except for the commas-->
    <case item="c"></case>

    <!-- works -->
    {{c.lastname}}, {{c.firstname}}
</div>
```

I've also tried inside of **caseload.tmpl.html**

```
<case ng-repeat="c in caseload" item="c"></case>
```

What do I need to do to get my directive to print the names? I know I am getting data because the second example works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

In **caseload.tmpl.html** I need to do:

```
<case ng-repeat="c in caseload" item="c"></case>
```

And in **case.tmpl.html** I need to do:

```
<div><span>{{item.lastname}}</span>, <span>{{item.firstname}}</span></div>
```